# Evaluating distance between two game board states in 2048 game

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces

I'm writing an AI program to play [2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2048_(video_game)) in python, you can try it [here](https://play2048.co/). For my [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_function) function I'd like to assess the distance between two board states, e.g. given 2 board states as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I'd like to know which one of them is closer to this one and by how much it is closer, when by "closer" I mean how many moves would it take to get from one board composition to the other:

[image]

since it's not regular matrix distance (the actions to get from one state to another are restricted to discrete set of moves) I'm not sure whether it's even possible. I thought of two approaches:

1. looking at the grid as a vector and subtracting cells and taking L16 norm. this will be calculated for every one of the 4 rotations of the grid, i.e. I don't care in which corner the 16 is and where exactly 4 is, only that it's in an adjacent cell.
2. looking at it as an indirect graph, but I didn't get far with this idea.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could refer me to some reading material on the subject or give me a lead?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you using this "closeness" for? I would think a better concept of closeness is "how many moves would it take to get from one to the other". Of course, that would depend upon the random tiles generated. But you can get an upper bound simply by taking the difference between the sums of the two sets of tiles and dividing by $2$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair that's exactly what I meant, I'll edit the post to make it more clear. your idea is interesting, could you explain to me why do I need to divide by 2? Thank you!

Comment: It is because the total value of the tiles increases by either $2$ or $4$ every turn - the value of the new tile added. If you assume the lowest possible increase of $2$ each turn, the number of moves between two positions in the same game will be half the difference in the total values of the tiles in the two positions.  So that is the maximum number of moves possible to get from one position to the other. Any time a $4$ tile is added instead results in fewer moves between them. I don't think it is a good heuristic function, though. The player's actions have no influence over it.

Comment: I had a similar abstract idea regarding chess? How many moves will turn one position to another? But I believe that at least for chess this will be too much calculations to work with, even theoretically. One solution might be to divide into islands, into connected components. So, you do not compare certain pairs of positions because they are just too different, there is no way they would transition into each other! Great post. Please update us!